# Find all the sub matrices( rectangles) in a NxN matrix

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given an NxN Matrix filled with 0's & numbers(1,2,3....k) 
such that k has a range [1,N].

Need to find all the sub-matrices i.e. rectangles in a given Matrix.

E.g.
2 3 4 0 0
1 2 5 0 0
1 3 4 0 0
0 0 0 1 1
1 4 0 3 4

So for this case
We have 3 sub-matrices
 2 3 4
 1 2 5
 1 3 4

1 4

1 1
3 4

What is the suitable algorithm to find out all the sub-matrices in a given matrix?
All the Sub-matrices should be a rectangle
E.g:
1 3 0
2 0 3
0 2 0

Answer is 4 sub matrices

1 3

3

2

2

Comment: What have you tried, and what is wrong with it?  And is it a requirement that a sub-matrix contains no 0's?

Comment: What would the result be for the 2x2 matrix `1 2 ; 3 0` (3 below 1, 0 below 2)?

Comment: Yes it is a requirement, I am able to find the way to get connected component using Depth First Search, but that doesnt check the rectangles part,every sub matrice Need to be rectangle.

Comment: But what should be the result for @interjay's example?

Comment: @JuanLopes: It can be either   1 2 & 3 - 2 Sub-matrices or 1 3 & 2
Aim is to find rectangles

Comment: Your expectations seem "non-deterministic". Which rule you take in place when you decide to take (1,3) instead of (1,2)T?

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem of finding all connected components in a graph.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29

Zero-based matrix elements are "delimiters", meaning that there is no connection, while non-zero adjacent elements are connected.

In the end, it boils down to your input. If you have guarantees you will always get a valid input, then this method will always produce valid output.
However, if have no such guarantees, then you'll need to do a simple post processing of discovered connected components where you will validate and filter each one.

Comment: I am aware of those connected components.
Connected Components need not to be Rectangle it can be of any shape.